# When joining multiple tables, the sum is a multiple of what it should be

Tags: sql

I have 4 tables:

- `employee`: `employee_id` (and several unrelated columns)
- `calls`: `employee_id`, `date`, `number_of_calls` (on that given date by employee)
- `employee_skills`: `employee_id`, `skills_id`
- `skills`: `skills_id`, `primary_skill`, `secondary_skill`

As a site note:
In `employee_skills` combinations of `primary_skill` and `secondary_skill` can occur several times with a different `skill_id`.
There can be two entries such as `234 | Python | Java` and `235 | Python | Java`.

I would like to have a `SELECTS`-statement that returns:
`employee_id`, `number_of_total_calls` (of that employee), `number_of_unique_secondary_skills`(of that employee)

The problem I am facing is regarding the `number_of_total_calls_of_employee`.
When I only join the tables `employee` and `calls`, I get the correct number (sum) of total calls of that employee.
However, when I also join the tables employee_skills and skills, I get a multiple of the correct number (e.g. 6 times the correct number for `employee_id` 123).
I think that this is the case since when doing so the `employee_id` occurs several times in the new table, not just once (the `employee_id` `123` occurs 6 times in the new table), since the `employee_id` is several times in the table `employee_skills` (e.g. the `employee_id` `123` occurs 6 times in `employee_skills`).

The `SELECT`-statement I am using looks as follows:

```
SELECT e.employee_id, SUM(c.number_of_calls), COUNT(DISTINCT s.secondary_skill)
FROM employees e
INNER JOIN calls c
ON e.employee_id = c.employee_id
INNER JOIN  employee_skills es
ON e.employee_id = es.employee_id
INNER JOIN skills s
ON es.skills_id = s.skills_id
GROUP BY e.employee_id;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you don't need the employees table, because `employee_id` is in both other tables.  I would then recommend aggregating along *both* dimensions before joining:

```
SELECT es.employee_id, c.number_of_calls, es.num_secondary_skills
FROM (SELECT c.employee_id, SUM(c.number_of_calls) as number_of_calls
      FROM calls c
      GROUP BY c.employe_id
     ) c JOIN
     (SELECT es.employee_id, COUNT(DISTINCT s.secondary_skill) as num_secondary_skills
      FROM employee_skills es JOIN
           skills s
           ON es.skills_id = s.skills_id
      GROUP BY es.employee_id
     ) es
     ON es.employee_id = c.employee_id;
```

The above only returns employees that both have calls and skills.  If some employees are missing one or the other, then they are filtered out.

If you want *all* employees, then the `employees` table is handy -- with outer joins:

```
SELECT e.employee_id, c.number_of_calls, es.num_secondary_skills
FROM employees e LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT c.employee_id, SUM(c.number_of_calls) as number_of_calls
      FROM calls c
      GROUP BY c.employe_id
     ) c
     ON c.employee_id = e.employee_id LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT es.employee_id, COUNT(DISTINCT s.secondary_skill) as num_secondary_skills
      FROM employee_skills es JOIN
           skills s
           ON es.skills_id = s.skills_id
      GROUP BY es.employee_id
     ) es
     ON es.employee_id = e.employee_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just take the sum of calls separately as an inner query.

```
SELECT e.employee_id,
( SELECT SUM(c.number_of_calls) FROM calls c WHERE c.employee_id = e.employee_id ) as sum_of_calls,
COUNT(DISTINCT s.secondary_skill)
FROM employees e
INNER JOIN calls c
ON e.employee_id = c.employee_id
INNER JOIN  employee_skills es
ON e.employee_id = es.employee_id
INNER JOIN skills s
ON es.skills_id = s.skills_id
GROUP BY e.employee_id;
```